# Hibernate-OneToMany mapping for existing DB Tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to join to Hibernate Entities in a OneToOne Mapping. I am able to fetch the data for a given primary key from the Main Entity, the joining entity, however, returns null. I am new to hibernate and any help will be appreciated.

I have two Tables,

**PT_CORE**

- Primary Key: ptId  - Integer;
- Foreign Key: stId(ST_AUX)  - Integer;
- Columns: ptId, ptName

**ST_AUX**

- Primary Key: stId;
- Columns: stId, stName

The two tables get populated by other applications and mine is a read-only operation.

Below is my first Entity class(PtCore.java)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PT_CORE")
public class PtCore implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="ptId", nullable = false)
    private int id; 

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int stId;  //The Foreign key column

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable( name = "core_aux", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(Name="ptId")},
                    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(Name="stId")}
                )
    private StAux staux;

    //Getters, setters and toString() for above 
}
```

StAux is another Entity, defined as below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ST_AUX")
public class StAux implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer stId;

    @OneToOne                       
    private PtCore ptcore;

    @Column
    private String stName;
    //Getters, Setters and toString follow.
}
```

I do below in the Service method:

```
PtCore obj = (PtCore) session.get(PtCore.class,1);
System.out.println(obj);
```

In the Results, I get the value of ptName, but the stAux class variables are null, Indicating that the join does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have the mapping information existing in your `PT_CORE`. And I assume it is something like `FOREIGN KEY (stid) REFERENCES (stid)`. If you want to use existing schema and existing data I guess there is no mapping table `core_aux` really existing. At least you did not mention it. However it is visible as `@JoinTable` annotation but still there is this above mentioned foreign key which seems to be the real mapping (so again not the join table).

I suggest the following

remove this

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private int stId;  //The Foreign key column
```

from your `PtCore`. I think it is not needed. Also in `PtCore`, remove the `@JoinTable` (because what I told above) and add mapping informaiion to `@OneToOne` annotation, like:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stid")
private StAux staux;
```

from your `PT_CORE`.

Then in  `StAux` alter also a bit:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "stid") // this might not be needed but if there is like "st_id"...
private Integer stId;  // so just for sure

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "staux") 
private PtCore ptcore;
```

Because you have existing tables and constraints there might raise errors if hibernate tries to auto-generate those again by JPA instructions.

Check [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438146/6413377) for more information.

**UPDATE**: just realized also that in your title is `@OneToMany` but in your code is `@OneToOne`.

So you might want to elaborate your question and/or title a bit.

Comment: I get the following error on trying the above solution :  ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

Comment: @SauravOjha You might need to check your hibernate configuration for auto generating stuff. I'll update my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

In your relation, the owning side is PtCore, the inverse side is StAux.

In bidirectional OneToOne relations, the inverse side has to have the `mappedBy` attribute. Actually, the `mappedBy` attribute contains the name of the association-field on the owning side.

So, you must change your inverse side code (StAux Entity). You have to add `mappedBy` attribute to `@OneToOne` in StAux class:

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="staux")                       
  private PtCore ptcore;
```